# Web automation

Tags: language-agnostic, automation

I'm developing an interface between an old web based application and another one. That old web-based application works fine but there no exists any API to communicate with.

There is any programmatic way to say a web-form something like: enter this value on this field, this one ins other and submit form?

**UPDATE:** I looking for something like this:

```
WebAutomation w = new WebAutomation("http://apphost/report");
w.forms[0].input[3].value = 123;
w.forms[0].input[4].value = "hello";
Response r = w.forms[0].submit();
...
```

Comment: Could you go into more detail, specially regarding your 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the tag on your question, the answer is going to be *highly* language specific.  There are also going to be wide range of solutions depending on how complex of a solution you are willing to implement and how flexible a result you are looking for.

On the one hand you can accomplish a lot in a very short period of time with something like Python's [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), but on the other hand, you can really get into the guts and have a lot of control by automating a browser using a COM object such as [SHDocVw](http://www.google.com/search?q=SHDocVw) (Windows-only, of course).

Or, as LoveMeSomeCode suggested, you can really hit your head against the concrete and start forging POST requests, but good-luck figuring out what the server expects if is doing any front-end processing of the form data.

EDIT:

One more option, if you are looking for something that you can come up to speed on quickly, is to use a [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)'s IE module, which basically provides a programmatic interface over an instance of Internet Explorer (its all COM in underneath, of course).  Keep in mind that this will likely be the least supportable option you could choose. I have personally used this to produce proof-of-concept automation suites that were then migrated to a more robust C# implementation where I handled the COM calls myself.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET: http://watin.sourceforge.net/

In ruby: http://wtr.rubyforge.org/

Cross platform: http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: These first two of these are testing frameworks and the third is macro-based, I'm not sure they are really suitable for the sort of routine automation he is thinking of performing.

Comment: Selenium would be hard for programming to do tasks like this. I've done it before but I know selenium fairly well but it's not designed for that sort of stuff.

Comment: You could use Selenium IDE (its a firefox plugin) to record what you want.  Then you don't have to write the code (although the generated code is probably not the best)

Answer (score 3):

You can, but you have to mock up a POST request. The fields (textboxes, radio buttons, etc.) are transmitted as key-value pairs back to the resource. You need to make a request for this resource(whichever one is used in the SUBMIT action for the FORM tag) and put all your field-value pairs in a POST payload no the request. 
 Here's a good program to see what values are being transmitted: http://www.httpwatch.com
 Or, you can use Firebug, a free Firefox extension.

Answer (score 2):

The Perl module [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) does exactly that. Your
example would look something like this:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$agent->get("http://apphost/report");
my $response = $agent->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        field_1_name => 123,
        field_2_name => "hello",
    },
);
```

There is also a Python port, and I guess similar libraries exist for many other languages.